# Two Virtualbox systems with same IP address

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, dhcp

I need to test an issue with nfs so I spun up a couple of VirtualBox VM's on my system.  One is RHEL7, another CentOS7.  Each has a unique MAC address when viewing settings> network.

Both VM's boot up fine, but `ip addr` shows the same IP address on both systems: 10.0.2.15.

How can I set up VirtualBox so that each instance has its own unique IP?  Is there an easy way of having it grab an IP from the host machine's local network via DHCP?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use bridged mode for the network interfaces of the VMs, they will use the network of the host system. They will ask for a network address just like the host, and they will be on the same network as the host. Each VM will get a unique IP address from the dhcp server on your network, just like any other computer on the network.